# Как сделать чтоб radio button тоже переключался?

Tags: jquery

Пример по ссылке.

```js
$("#all-value div label").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#all-value div label").removeClass('active-button');
 $(this).addClass('active-button');
  })
```

```css
.location {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px; }

.active-button {
  background: #fff !important;
  border: 1px solid #3EBBEF; }

#all-value > div > label {
  display: block;
  background: #E8E8E8;
  color: #686868;
  width: 208px;
  height: 50px; }

.location-mask {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 208px;
  margin: 10px 16px; }
  .location-mask > h3 {
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    font-size: 14px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <div id="all-value">
  <div class="location-mask"><label><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="is-selected" class="location">1</label></div>
  <div class="location-mask"><label><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="is-selected" class="location">2</label></div>
  <div class="location-mask"><label class="active-button"><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="selected" class="location" checked> 3</label></div>
 </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mars_092/8ytbef52/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#all-value div label").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#all-value div label").removeClass('active-button');
                $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
                $(this).addClass('active-button');
            })
```

Достаточно добавить одну строку.

Comment: огромное спасибо!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#all-value div label").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#all-value div label").removeClass('active-button');
  $(this).addClass('active-button');
  $(this).find(".location").prop("checked", true);
})
```

```css
.location {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.active-button {
  background: #fff !important;
  border: 1px solid #3EBBEF;
}
#all-value > div > label {
  display: block;
  background: #E8E8E8;
  color: #686868;
  width: 208px;
  height: 50px;
}
.location-mask {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 208px;
  margin: 10px 16px;
}
.location-mask > h3 {
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="all-value">
    <div class="location-mask">
      <label>
        <input name="dzen" type="radio" value="is-selected" class="location">1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="location-mask">
      <label>
        <input name="dzen" type="radio" value="is-selected" class="location">2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="location-mask">
      <label class="active-button">
        <input name="dzen" type="radio" value="selected" class="location" checked>3</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо!!